# how to get dropdown (HTML Select) text against it value from local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on an existing project where I have to get the dropdown (HTML select) Text against its selected value in jquery.

I am storing the dropdown value in localstorage to get the value again if the user refreshed the page so I can maintain the same text against its value.

For demonstration, I created a similar code. My desired output will be:
If the value is `0` then in the console it should print `Select Value...`

```html
<select class="form-control " id="test" name="test" placeholder="Select Value...">
  <option value="0">Select Value...</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var value = $("#test").val(),
    currentTestValue = localStorage.getItem("test_selected_value");

  if (currentTestValue === undefined || currentTestValue === '' || currentTestValue === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("test_selected_value", 0);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("test_selected_value", value);
  }

  var textValue = $("#test").options[value.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(textValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have set the value of the select - The selected text value will be:
$("#test option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0):

`find()` is used to retrieve child elements from the DOM. Using an integer (in a string) is not a valid selector.

To find an `option` within a `select` by its value you can use an attribute selector or `filter()`:

```
var textValue = $("#test option").filter((i, opt) => opt.value == value).text();
```

Also note that the logic to set the `localStorage` item can be simplified. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#test").val();
  var currentTestValue = localStorage.getItem("test_selected_value");    
  localStorage.setItem("test_selected_value", currentTestValue || value);

  var textValue = $("#test option").filter((i, opt) => opt.value == value).text();
  console.log(textValue);
});
```

[**Example in jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmage8s/) - as the SO snippet editor restricts access to localStorage.

Comment: Where did you use localstorage to get the text?
If I have to retrieve value from dropdowns can directly retrieve it by:var textValue = $("#test").find('option:selected').text().trim()

Comment: I want to retrieve it from localstorage

Comment: I used `getItem`, as per your original.

Comment: I am storing the dropdown value in localstorage to get the value again if the user refreshed the page so I can maintain the same text against its value. But in your answer you getting value from localstorage but textValue variable you are getting value through DOM

Comment: Right, because your original did. In this line: `textValue = $("#category_filter").find(value).text;` That line is syntactically wrong, which is what my answer fixes, as described above. The output in the fiddle is also as you requested.